# Onchange event not triggering when using the minus sign

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onchange

I'm experiencing a weird issue, or maybe it's something that i simply don't know

i am using an input type text to capture and update a value using ajax.

```
<input type="text" onchange="functionx(this);" style="width:80px; margin-top: 5px;" name="stock" id="stock" />
```

if i put any alphanumeric value on the field the javascript function get fired correctly, even if i put the plus sign and some numbers (+123456) but if i use the minus sign it doesn't work (-123456) what am i missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
function functionx(obj){
  alert("function is being called");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? possibly a fiddle?

Comment: What's the function you're using?

Comment: I'd use `onkeyup` or `onkeypress` instead of `onchange`

Comment: The function isn't relevant it's simply that the onchange event isn't working right now everything on the function is empty except for a single alert to check what is happening. See my update

Comment: @SquareCat i need the onchange `onchange` event not the `onkeyup` or `onkeypress` that's why the question is entitled as such.

Comment: Hmmm... seems to work okay for me here http://jsbin.com/uRUrEqIt/1/edit.   You can test and see that any value, even -123456 works correctly.

Comment: @Charlie74 yes i see it working (by the way) fix the link since there is some extra text in there, but in my local code, with the exact same code is not working when i put the (-) sign infront of the string

Comment: What browser / OS are you using?

Comment: @DannyG really strange that it would work for you in the jsbin, but not on your regular site.   Hmmm....

Comment: Firefox on it's latest version, Chrome and IE 11, i test my sites in every one of these three browsers at first.

Comment: I just rewrote the code by hand in a new file and it's working now, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate in your JS that you are comparing with a NULL or undefined value and not with a value who is bigger than 0, i tested this on jsFiddle and its working fine.

Something in your validation could be causing this issue.

```
function functionx(obj){
 var objval = obj.value;
  if(objval != ""){
     alert(objval);
  }  
}
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x87TS/6/)

Comment: Thanks, i fixed this i was checking if the value was above 0

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, while working on a project.

My answer does not exactly address the OP, but might help people running into the similar issue, due to a different reason.

I had an input field, which needed only Natural numbers as input. Therefore inside the onChange handler, I would run a validation, as shown in below code snippet.

```
<input
  ...
  // AREA OF FOCUS
  type="number"

  // AREA OF FOCUS
  onChange={(event) => {                    
  const isValid = validateNumberValue(event.target.value, 'REGEX FOR NATURAL NUMBER');
  if (isValid) {                                          
      handleFormInputChange();
     }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

It would work perfectly for the most part, however it would also accept input such as `--, ++`. Upon investigation, I figured it was due to the onChange handler not triggering when `+ or -` was entered as input.

This was because, the `type` attribute of the `input` HTML tag was `"number"`. It would only trigger when a numeric value was entered. I changed the `type` field to `text`, and everything started working as expected.

```
<input
      ...
      // AREA OF FOCUS
      type="text"
      onChange={(event) => { ... }}
      ...
/>
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.